# Custom Colors are not recognized for Wear OS

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, android-resources, android-color

I am developing a wear application in android studio. I defined my colors in

res->color->colors.xml ( [image: Here is my folder structre])

When I open a new project for phone or tablet, colors.xml is placed in values folder by Android studio. But this time for wear project Android studio created new folder called color and placed the colors.xml automatically inside it.

The thing is I cannot use colors defined in colors.xml for wear project.

**colors.mxl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<color android:name="colorPrimary">#006064</color>
<color android:name="colorPrimaryDark">#004c40</color>
<color android:name="colorAccent">#82b1ff</color>
<color android:name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>

</selector>
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:boxedEdges="all">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmailEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" --->THERE IS AN ERROR HERE
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPasswordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Parola"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/done_white"
        android:text="Giriş"
        android:onClick="attemptLogin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

When I'd like to use them in my activity_login.xml file none of the custom colors (colorPrimary,colorPrimaryDark etc..) are not recognized and android studio gives the following error.

> error: resource color/colorAccent (aka com.muhendis.diabetwatch:color/colorAccent) not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource color/colorAccent (aka com.muhendis.diabetwatch:color/colorAccent) not found., sources=[/Users/muhendis/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/DiabetWatch/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_login.xml:32], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

So my question is how to get rid of this error and define custom colors when developing wear app?

### EDIT

It is colors.xml not colors.mxl. I misspelled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of mistakes visible. It's not clear how many are in your code and how many are just in your SO question, but fix these and I'll bet it'll work:

1. You named the file `colors.**mxl**` at one point. Spelling matters!
2. It needs to be in `res\values`, not `res\color`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. colors.mxl is my bad I misspelled it when asking. I edited the question. The thing is when you try to add resource file and select color (right click res -> New -> Android Resource File -> Resource Type: Color, File Name: colors.xml)  Android Studio is adding colors.xml in color directory in res automatically. (res->color->colors.xml) I dont know why Android Studio is adding like this even though it is not recognized in layouts. Adding to res\values is working. Thanks.

Comment: It's because this isn't a color resource **file**. Its root XML element is `resources`, meaning that the file can contain multiple items, which are resource _values_ specified by their individual XML elements. So, it goes in the `values` subdir. Other resource files contain a single item specified by its pathname, like `res\color\my_dynamic_color.xml`.

Comment: Now I understood the difference. @String You're perfect thanks :)